# Regex 'and' operator

Tags: java, regex

I am working on a WebView console, and I wanna use regex for detect color codes in string. I have an expression:

```
(&(?<colorIndex>\d|[eadfcblmor]))?(?<text>[^(&\d|[eadfcblmor])]+)
```

It only matching when the colorIndex is followed by a text. Example:

```
&1Hello &2World&1!
```

('Hello' is blue, 'World' is green, '!' is blue)

I want to add formats in the text(bold, italic, etc.), so I need to detect format changes when the colorIndex is doesn't followed by text. Example:

```
&1Hello &l&2World &r&1&!
```

('Hello' is blue, 'World' is bold and green, '!' is normal and blue)

But I the '&l&2World' is only get colored, because the '§l' doesn't followed by text.

What I need to change in the expression to do that?

Thanks, and sorry for my bad english!

**EDIT:**

WebViewConsole.class:

```
public class WebViewConsole {

    WebView console;
    String contentHtml = "";

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(&(?<colorIndex>\\d|[eadfcblmor]))?(?<text>[^(&\\d|[eadfcblmor])]+)");

    char[] colors = {'1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'e', 'a', 'd', 'f', 'c', 'b'};
    String[] formats = {"o", "l", "m"};

    public WebViewConsole() {
        console = new WebView();
    }

    public List<String> getHtmlFormat(String text) {
        List<String> formats = new ArrayList<>();
        String color = "white";
        String format = "normal";

        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
        while (matcher.find()) {
            String codeInText = matcher.group("colorIndex");
            String textInText = matcher.group("text");

            if (codeInText != null/* && codeInText.matches("\\d|[eadfcblmor]+")*/) {
                if (isFormat(codeInText)) {
                    format = getFormatName(codeInText);
                } else {
                    color = getFormatName(codeInText);
                }

            } else {
                color = "white";
                format = "normal";
            }

            if (codeInText != null && codeInText.matches("\\d|[eadfcblmor]+")) {
                formats.add("<span style=\"color:" + color + ";font-weight:" + format + "\">" + textInText + "</span>");
            }
        }
        return formats;
    }

    public void appendText(String text) {
        for (String htmlText : getHtmlFormat(text)) {
            contentHtml += htmlText.replaceAll("\\n", "<br>");
        }
        //contentHtml += "<br>";
        getConsole().getEngine().loadContent(contentHtml);
    }

    public WebView getConsole() {
        return console;
    }

    public boolean isFormat(String code) {
        if (!code.equalsIgnoreCase("r")) {
            for (String format : formats) {
                if (format.equals(code)) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public String getFormatName(String code) {
        switch (code) {
            case "1":
                return "blue";
            case "2":
                return "darkgreen";
            case "l":
                return "bold";
            case "o":
                return "bold";
        }
        return null;
    }

    public void clear() {
        contentHtml = "";
        getConsole().getEngine().loadContent(contentHtml);
    }
}
```

Comment: can you list a few examples for valid uses of color-coded text? Currently, your expression contains a bunch of weird syntax (that I suspect is not intentional), but I can't figure out where exactly the errors are without knowing the full extent of your color-coding syntax.

Comment: I edited the question.

Comment: I know this doesn't answer the actual question, but "now you have two problems". Don't use RegExps for this, parse the string character by character.

Comment: I know, but I changed because that doesn't worked. I only tried this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution with a little help.

I changed the regex from:

```
(&(?<colorIndex>\d|[eadfcblmor]))?(?<text>[^(&\d|[eadfcblmor])]+)
```

To:

```
(&(?<colorIndex>\d|[eadfcblmor]))?(?<text>[^(&\d|[eadfcblmor])]*)
```